# How to redirect to error page in angularjs with various error message

Tags: angularjs

I need to redirect to an error page for all the angularjs exceptions. In addition, I would like to show different error message in the error page. I searched around and saw that I can override $exceptionHandler to redirect:

```
app.factory('$exceptionHandler', ['$injector', function($injector) {

    var $location;

    return function(exception, cause) {
        $location = $location || $injector.get('$location');
        $location.path("/error");
    };
}]);
```

However, I'm not sure how I should set the error message? Also, shall I include $exceptionHandler in each controller because it has been overrided?

Comment: BTW, is there a way that  I can use $provide.decorator to do the same task?